# CSS scale between start and end point with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to write a small script that calculates a scale transform value between a `min` and `max` range, based on a certain scroll distance.

For Example:

`var min = 1;
var max = 1.3;
var distance = window.innerHeight;
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;`

For context, the transform should happen over the length of one window scroll. The landing of this page is a full screen background, so the distance will always be completed once a full window scroll has occurred.

I have also played around with `getBoundingClientRect().top` on the container below as once it falls below 0 you know the transform should be completed, but again, no such luck.

I have tried many different ways but haven't come close to generating the number i need, so mainly i am looking for the process of generating the proper number. I'm not using any external libraries or plugins, please do not suggest jquery or GSAP. Any tips or examples are greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please provide bits of your "many different ways" or at least a more precise example.

Comment: There isn't really much point. I haven't generated anything close to the number i want so posting something like `transformValue = distance / scrollTop * 100` which is the kind of stuff i am trying, isn't even close as it decreases instead of increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the math you are looking for.

```
transformValue = min + (max - min) * Math.min(scrollTop / distance, 1);
```

Comment: exactly! thank you man. I'm curious if you pulled this from somewhere, if this is a common technique... or you just know how to math? I didn't have anything close to this...

Comment: No, I just wrote it off the top of my head. I had to do stuff like that a lot when I was making an HTML5 game engine. This is called `linear interpolation` or `LERP`.

Comment: sweet, i'll look into it. Thanks again.